# Popen file descriptor difference between Python 2.6 and 2.7+ on Linux

Tags: python, python-2.7, subprocess, popen, python-2.6

I have a really odd problem. I have some code that requires a Linux file descriptor (/dev/fd/N) where N is some number. The following example code demonstrates effectively what is being done.

In order to run the code create a file called "/tmp/test" with some text in it.

The code works in Python 2.6, but in Python 2.7 or later, I get:

```
cat: /dev/fd/4: No such file or directory
```

Can anyone figure out why? And what needs to change for the following code to work on 2.7 and later. Assume that I cannot change needing file descriptors (/dev/fd/4 for example):

Here is the code:

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

data = Popen(
    ["cat"],
    stdin=open('/tmp/test', 'rb'),
    stdout=PIPE,
    universal_newlines=True).stdout

fd_name = '/dev/fd/%d' % data.fileno()

fddata = Popen(
    ["cat",
    fd_name],
    stdout=PIPE,
    universal_newlines=True,).stdout

print(fddata.read())
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why this code would appear to work on Python 2.6, the problem is fundamentally that "cat" and your Python code are in different processes which will have different associations between fd numbers and the underlying file.

To achieve the specific effect of gifting a subprocess a file descriptor, you'll need to duplicate that fd into the subprocess. This requires interacting with the OS at a somewhat lower level than Popen, and I don't know off the top of my head how best to do that from Python.

Perhaps there's an easier way to achieve the end goal you're looking for? Can you give us more information about what problem you're trying to solve and what constraints your code is under?

Comment: Please read the [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) help page. Include code, what you have tried, the original (if any), the result you got or didn't get, and what you expected to get.